# How can I substitute a command when a particular character is not present in a font?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I have a document I'm working on that makes use of a somewhat unusual character, the letter "y" with a macron:  ȳ

Recently, I decided to switch fonts for a certain part of the document, Latin Modern Typewriter Prop. The document itself is typeset with LuaLaTeX and fontspec. This font works perfectly for my purposes, save for one problem, ȳ isn't present in it! Now, I was able to come up with a hack-ish work around:

```
\newcommand{\yn}{%
    \phantom{y}\kern -1ex%
    \=i\kern -0.678ex%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0.2pt}%
    \colorbox{white}{\color{white}\i}\kern -1ex y}
```

[image]

Essentially, what this does is overlays the letter "i" with macron, ī, with a dotless i,  ı, in white, leaving only the macron visible, and then overlays that with the letter "y".

The problem is that I already have a lot of code using `\=y` to typeset ȳ that would be incredibly time consuming to change over. On top of that, should I ever switch fonts again (or if the current font gets a character for ȳ), it would be nice to not have to change things back.

So basically, my question is this: using fontspec (or whatever), is there any way I can make it so that when a particular character is not found, a particular command is substituted in place?

Comment: I don't understand the problem as to why `\=y` becomes unacceptable under the font change.

Comment: no what I mean is that, I was using ``\=y`` but if I wanted to use my work around, I'd have to change it to ``\yn``. What I would like is to somehow change the behavior of ``\=y`` such that it uses ``\yn``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better solution requires two steps: first you have to undeclare the composition `\=y` and then redefine `ȳ` to do the composition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Prop}

\UndeclareUTFcomposite{x0233}{\=}{y}
\newunicodechar{ȳ}{\=y}

\begin{document}

ȳ \textsf{ȳ} \texttt{ȳ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For making the combination work in `\url` you have to teach it to the package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Prop}

\UndeclareUTFcomposite{x0233}{\=}{y}
\newunicodechar{ȳ}{\=y}
\makeatletter % for url
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\do\ȳ{\=y}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

ȳ \textsf{ȳ} \texttt{ȳ}

\url{www.ȳ.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Updates

With the versions of XeTeX and `fontspec` current on January 2017, the input for XeLaTeX can be simplified, because the Harfbuzz library will take care of the composites by itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{url}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Prop}

\makeatletter % for url
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\do\ȳ{\hbox{ȳ}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

ȳ \textsf{ȳ} \texttt{ȳ}

\url{www.ȳ.com}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, this won't work with LuaLaTeX, so it can be better to use code that works with both engines. So, let's assume we have a text fonts with the ȳ glyph, but the monospaced font doesn't.

One can define a new encoding for the problematic font, in this case I call it `TUy` (the name is unimportant, so long as it is unique), based on the now default TU encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter % reading tuenc.def needs it
\DeclareUnicodeEncoding{TUy}{
  \input{tuenc.def}% the new encoding is based on TU
  \UndeclareComposite{\=}{y}% but with a change
}
\makeatother

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}

\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Prop}[
  NFSSEncoding=TUy
]

\newunicodechar{ȳ}{\=y}
\makeatletter % for url
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\do\ȳ{\hbox{\=y}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

ȳ \textsf{ȳ} \texttt{ȳ}

\url{www.ȳ.com}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to get this work inside of the ``\url`` command with hyperref? Right now, if I enter ``\url{http://www.\=y.com}``, the result is ``http://www.y\char"0304\relax.com``

Comment: @KevinKeith Did you try directly entering `ȳ`?

Comment: well strangely, when I enter it directly, like so ``\url{http://www.ȳ.com}``, the ``ȳ`` just doesn't show up at all. ``\texttt{ȳ}`` works fine though

Comment: @KevinKeith I added the workaround for `\url`, but don't expect the string will point to the right URL.

Comment: Sure, that's fine.

Comment: One more question: is there anyway to get it so that ``\=y`` could work with BibLaTeX/Biber? For example, if I had an entry (using the Typewriter Prop font) that had an entry like ``url="http://www.\=y.com"``? Strangely, ``url="http://www.\=i.com"``, for instance, works just fine. Thanks for all your help in any case

Comment: @KevinKeith That warrants a new question with the details

Comment: Your last example no longer compiles without error. One needs a \makeatletter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Around `\DeclareUnicodeEncoding` I presume

Comment: Yes, naturally.  Sorry ;-)