# Why does the log entry complain about a circumflex character that is not in the source code?

Tags: xetex, font-encodings, logging

Question in other words: Why does the log output complain about a character that was not given in the source code input?

## Let's get hexidecimal

UTF-8 hexadecimal representations are used here, because my file uses unicode characters encoded in UTF-8. I am therefore using `xelatex` and `fontspec` to typeset.

### Source Code Input Analyzed

Here it can be seen that **5c** (backslash) is followed by **5e** ([circumflex accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/005E/index.htm)).
Relevant part of hexadecimal representation of utf-8 encoded source code:

```
 00000a0: 7d0a 5c5e 320a 5c65 6e64 7b64 6f63 756d  }.\^2.\end{docum
```

### Log Output Analyzed

Here it can be seen an error corresponding to the input source code resulted in an error, namely that character **cc 82** ([combining circumflex accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0302/index.htm)) is missing (UTF-8 has multibyte characters).

```
0004d40: 6163 7465 723a 2054 6865 7265 2069 7320  acter: There is
0004d50: 6e6f 20cc 8220 696e 2066 6f6e 7420 5b2e  no .. in font [.
```

## Example

Reproduce the problem using Verdana.ttf, although I am using a different font that I am not permitted to share here due to legal reasons.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Path = ../../Resources/Fonts/ ,
  Extension = .ttf ,
  UprightFont = *,
]{Verdana}
\begin{document}
\^2
\end{document}
```

## Terminal Output

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./JiraCircumflexIsolated.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.13> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (./JiraCircumflexIsolated.aux) [1] (./JiraCircumflexIsolated.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on JiraCircumflexIsolated.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on JiraCircumflexIsolated.log.
```

## Log Output

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.10.4)  18 OCT 2017 10:41
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**JiraCircumflexIsolated.tex
(./JiraCircumflexIsolated.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.13> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (loader) 
 (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2017/09/18 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count87
\l_tmpa_int=\count88
\l_tmpb_int=\count89
\g_tmpa_int=\count90
\g_tmpb_int=\count91
\g__intarray_font_int=\count92
\g__prg_map_int=\count93
\c_log_iow=\count94
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count96
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count97
\l__iow_indent_int=\count98
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count99
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count100
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count108
\l__sort_length_int=\count109
\l__sort_min_int=\count110
\l__sort_top_int=\count111
\l__sort_max_int=\count112
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count113
\l__sort_block_int=\count114
\l__sort_begin_int=\count115
\l__sort_end_int=\count116
\l__sort_A_int=\count117
\l__sort_B_int=\count118
\l__sort_C_int=\count119
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count120
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count121
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count122
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count123
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count125
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count126
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count127
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count128
\l__regex_balance_int=\count129
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count130
\l__regex_mode_int=\count131
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count132
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count133
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count134
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count135
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count136
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count137
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count138
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count139
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count140
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count141
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count142
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count143
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count144
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count145
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count146
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count147
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count151
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count152
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count153
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count154
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count155
\l__regex_step_int=\count156
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count157
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count158
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count159
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count160
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count161
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count162
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count163
\g__debug_trace_regex_int=\count164
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen109
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen123
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen124
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\g__driver_image_int=\count165
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2017/09/18 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count166
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count167
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count168
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count169
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count170
)
Package: fontspec 2017/09/22 v2.6e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2017/09/22 v2.6e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count171
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count172
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count173
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count174
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count175
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
 (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
 (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
File: tuenc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 479.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 483.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 487.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 491.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 495.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 499.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 503.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 507.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setromanfont with sig. 'O{}mO{}' on line 511.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 515.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mO{}mO{}' on line 519.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 523.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 527.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeature with sig. 'm' on line 531.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 535.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 539.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 543.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newICUfeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 547.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 551.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 555.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 559.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 563.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 567.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \IfFontFeatureActiveTF with sig. 'mmm' on line 571.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCommand with sig. 'mO{}m' on line 3563.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingAccent with sig. 'mm' on line 3569.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingSymbol with sig. 'mm' on line 3575.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingComposite with sig. 'mmm' on line 3581.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \EncodingCompositeCommand with sig. 'mmm' on line 3587.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareUnicodeEncoding with sig. 'mm' on line 3612.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareSymbol with sig. 'm' on line 3618.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \UndeclareComposite with sig. 'mm' on line 3626.
.................................................
 (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3804.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3809.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3814.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3819.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3849.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3874.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 3925.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 4020.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 4024.
.................................................
))
\g__fontspec_family_Verdana_int=\count179
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'Verdana(0)' created for font 'Verdana' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX,Path = ../../Resources/Fonts/,Extension = .ttf,UprightFont =
. *].
.  
.  This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
.  
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
. <->"[../../Resources/Fonts/Verdana.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
.................................................
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 7.
 (./JiraCircumflexIsolated.aux)
\openout1 = `JiraCircumflexIsolated.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 8.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/Verdana(0)/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/Verdana(0)/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/Verdana(0)/m/n --> TU/Verdana(0)/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/Verdana(0)/m/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/Verdana(0)/bx/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/Verdana(0)/m/n --> TU/Verdana(0)/bx/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/Verdana(0)/bx/it on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 8.
Missing character: There is no ̂ in font [../../Resources/Fonts/Verdana.ttf]/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;!
 [1

] (./JiraCircumflexIsolated.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10048 strings out of 492998
 234670 string characters out of 6134491
 301486 words of memory out of 5000000
 14072 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 530312 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 35i,4n,65p,10375b,236s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on JiraCircumflexIsolated.pdf (1 page).
```

---

## Notes

- TeX Live 2017
- `xelatex`
- `fontspec`
- Verdana typeface

Comment: I don't get a missing char, but `\^` is a command that tries to print a certain char, and if your version of verdana (or some other font) doesn't have it then you get this message.

Comment: in TU encoding the `\^` accent is defined to use the combining accent character if there is not a pre-composed glyph specified, fontspec gives ways to change that and declare a font specific encoding that uses (say) the classic tex `\accent` construct.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330663/how-can-i-substitute-a-command-when-a-particular-character-is-not-present-in-a-f/330672#330672 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330663/how-can-i-substitute-a-command-when-a-particular-character-is-not-present-in-a-f/330672#330672

Comment: Page numbers are not in the source code, but you find them in the output. Similarly, `\^` eventually tries to use U+0302 (`0xcc 0x82` in UTF-8). The “missing character” warning comes from the deep level of TeX, when it's translating lists of typesetting commands into “printable output” and needs to access information from the font. The `\^` command no longer exists, as it has already been expanded into typesetting commands, so TeX can't know where the instruction of printing U+0302 came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on useful comments from the usual TeX.Stackexchange Crew,
I came up with this.

The documentation in `fontspec` is not particularly strong here-probably because it is complicated and involves other components-so I had to do this by trial and error.

## Steps to make it work

- Get rid of Verdana because that does not have the circumflex character as desired. I just looked for it in a directory full of fonts with `otfinfo -u * | grep 005E`
- Declare my own unicode encoding with a salient name using `\DeclareUnicodeEncoding`
- Set the `\^`, which originally represents the combined circumflex to represent the circumflex.
- Apply this encoding in the `fontspec` font definition using the key NFSSEncoding.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\DeclareUnicodeEncoding{preventcombinedcircumflex}{
  \input{tuenc.def}% adds U+00A0 in the case of empty args \^{}
  \EncodingAccent{\^}{"005E}
}%
\makeatother

\setmainfont[
  Path = ../../Resources/Fonts/ ,
  Extension = .otf ,
  UprightFont = *-Roman,
  NFSSEncoding= preventcombinedcircumflex,
]{SomeTypefaceThatHasNoCombinedCircumflexAndOnlyCircumFlex}

\begin{document}
\^2
\end{document}
```

## CAVEAT

In my project, I unwittingly produced a non-breakable space U+00A0 (utf-8 hex c2a0), which is also not supported by my typeface. This was caused by a definition in the `tuenc.def`  file.

```
\def\add@unicode@accent#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax^^a0\else#2\fi
  \char#1\relax}
```

The fix can be found here: [Why is my circumflex \^ mapping to a non-breakable space U+00A0 when followed by {} using a custom encoding \DeclareUnicodeEncoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396855/why-is-my-circumflex-mapping-to-a-non-breakable-space-u00a0-when-followed-by)

### Notes

- `xunicode.sty` defines the `\^` as `\DeclareEncodedCompositeCharacter{\UTFencname}{\^}{0302}{02C6}  % Combining circumflex accent`

Comment: You should load tuenc.def in your encoding (add \makeatletter before it), try out `\textquotedblright` to see why it matters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! This was almost a life saver. Unfortunately, I ran into another snag. I opened a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396855/why-is-my-circumflex-mapping-to-a-non-breakable-space-u00a0-when-followed-by