# Why is my circumflex \^ mapping to a non-breakable space U+00A0 when followed by {} using a custom encoding \DeclareUnicodeEncoding?

Tags: xetex, font-encodings, logging

Using `\DeclareUnicodeEncoding`, I defined my own encoding that adjusts the `\^` such that it maps to a circumflex accent U+005E rather than to a combining circumflex accent U+0302 (which is already set by xunicode to represent the modified letter accent U+02C6).

I hit a few bumps/snags/hurdles.

1. The first problem was caused by a circumflex appearing in `listings` environments that was solved by adding `\input{tuenc.def}` (with `\makeatletter`).
2. The second problem appears when typing `\^{}`, which causes a log error.

## Log Error

```
file.log:505:Missing character: There is no   in font [/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/rozynski/comicneue/ComicNeue_Regular.otf]/OT:mapping=tex-text;!
```

## Code

See comments in the code. Note that I picked ComicNeue_Regular.otf specifically because it does not support U+0302 or U+00A0, and it is contained within TeX Live.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\DeclareUnicodeEncoding{preventcombinedcircumflex}{
  \input{tuenc.def}
  \EncodingAccent{\^}{"005E}
}%
\makeatother

\setmainfont[
  Path = /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/rozynski/comicneue/ ,
  Extension = .otf ,
  UprightFont = *_Regular,
  NFSSEncoding= preventcombinedcircumflex,
]{ComicNeue}

\begin{document}
% Solved the general issue by adding \EncodingAccent{\^}{"005E}, or so I thought.
\^2
% Solved the lstlisting issue was solved by adding \makeatletter\input{tuenc.def}
\begin{lstlisting}
|^2
\end{lstlisting}
% Unsolved
\^{}
\end{document}
```

---

## Notes

- This is a bit of a follow-up to another question:  [Why does the log entry complain about a circumflex character that is not in the source code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396751/why-does-the-log-entry-complain-about-a-circumflex-character-that-is-not-in-the/396765?noredirect=1#comment987154_396765)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add

```
\catcode160=15
```

then you find

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.84   \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax 
                                     \else#2\fi
?
```

which is... interesting and translates as: it's not your fault..

The offending line is

```
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax^^a0\else#2\fi
```

which says if the argument of the accent command is empty use a non breaking space. You need *something* as when using unicode combining characters you don't want `a\"{}`  to put the accent on the `a` because the following combining character had no base to act on.

But your example shows it's not safe to use `^^a0` . Instead of inputting `tuenc.def` input a local copy where

```
\def\add@unicode@accent#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax^^a0\else#2\fi
  \char#1\relax}
```

has been changed to (I guess)

```
\def\add@unicode@accent#1#2{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\space\else#2\fi
  \char#1\relax}
```

perhaps we should use space always. I'll raise it with the team....

Comment: Very interesting indeed. `\catcode160` is a non-breakable space  which you set to category code 15, correct?

Comment: @JonathanKomar just as a debugging aid catcode 15 is invalid character so tex stops at the point the character first got into the system. I added a fix to my answer.

Comment: Wait, wouldn't it be much better to put the redefinition in @JonathanKomar's code after loading `tuenc.def` rather than producing yet another `.def` file that would be a slight variant of `tuenc.def`??